# How to call a stored procedure synchronously with SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, simplejdbccall

I was running a stored procedure with Springs `SimpleJdbcCall` like this:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("example_proc");
jdbcCall.execute();
// do other stuff on other subsystems
// the sysout below is just an example - the real scenario was somewhat different
System.out.println("Supposedly after the end of the stored procedure call");
```

The stored procedure was running for a long time, and it was overlapped with the stuff that was supposed to happen after that.

The stored procedure was written in Microsoft's SQL Server dialect, and looked like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example_proc
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO example_table_1 SELECT * FROM example_table_2
    UPDATE example_table_1 SET col1 = 'a' WHERE ...
END
```

The question is: how to make sure the `SimpleJdbcCall` waits until the stored procedure finishes?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack for this: make the stored procedure return something, and then retrieve it in the jdbc call.

The is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example_proc
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO example_table_1 SELECT * FROM example_table_2
    UPDATE example_table_1 SET col1 = 'a' WHERE ...

    -- this is just a hack for running it synchronously:
    SELECT 1 AS success
END
```

Now that it returns something, the jdbc call can wait for that:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withProcedureName("example_proc").
        returningResultSet("success", new SingleColumnRowMapper<Integer>());
Map<String, Object> map = jdbcCall.execute();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Integer> storedProcedureResults = (List<Integer>) map.get(success);
int result = storedProcedureResults.get(0);
// I did something to the result. I am not sure if this is really necessary.
// But I was worried if the jvm or javac would optimize the dead code.
// I returned the value from a method. Printing it should also be enough.
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this will run as synchronously, I tried and waited for the result-set and extracted values of OUTPUT type param still it ran as asynchronously.